# What is the best way I can automatically enforce S3 server access logging?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an event rule on the CloudTrail event "CreateBucket", and I'm using the following Lambda:

```
import boto3
import time
import logging
s3client = boto3.client('s3')
s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
ssmclient = boto3.client('ssm')
stsclient = boto3.client('sts')
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError
logger = logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def lambda_handler(event, context):
        logger.info(event)
        account_id = stsclient.get_caller_identity()["Account"]
        serveraccessloggingbucket = "acct-"+account_id+"-serveraccesslogging1"
        bucketName = event['detail']['requestParameters']['bucketName']
        getbucketLogging = s3client.get_bucket_logging(Bucket= bucketName)
          try:
            applybucketlogging = s3client.put_bucket_logging(Bucket= bucketName, BucketLoggingStatus={'LoggingEnabled': {'TargetBucket': serveraccessloggingbucket,'TargetPrefix': bucketName}},)
            logger.info("Applying Logging To S3 Bucket")
        except ClientError as e:
            statuscode = getbucketLogging['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode']
            if statuscode == 200:
                print("Target Bucket Logging is Not Found")
                applybucketlogging = s3client.put_bucket_logging(Bucket= bucketName, BucketLoggingStatus={'LoggingEnabled': {'TargetBucket': serveraccessloggingbucket,'TargetPrefix': bucketName}},)
            else:
                exit()
        except Exception as e:
            logger.info(str(e))
```

However, it's not working. This is logical, perhaps, since the CreateBucket event has already happened by the time the function could be invoked... any ideas? The goal is to automatically ensure server access logging is always enabled for every S3 bucket, even if the user forgets to set that during bucket creation.

Comment: Whats not working in your question? Does it not trigger, does it not error?

Comment: The lambda simply doesn't cause buckets I create to have server access logging automatically enabled, which is my goal. I create a bucket without server access logging... and I wait for the server access logging to be enabled... nothing happens.

Comment: Have you enabled the logging of S3 API calls? https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/cloudtrail-logging.html. Without this it won't ever trigger

Comment: Yes - CloudTrail is enabled. Config is enabled. All of my services are enabled, and I'm seeing the Config alerts that buckets don't have server access logging enabled. However, the Lambda is not causing my buckets to automatically enable server access logging as intended.

Comment: So the Lambda does execute? But it doesn’t successfully run? Can you not check your CloudWatch logs?

Comment: Hi Lorena if you can confirm that the Lambda function is in fact being invoked it’ll just help to rule out other steps

Comment: Yes, it's invoked. I see it invoked in the cloudwatch logs when I create a bucket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case anyone else has this same question, the best way to enforce Server Access Logging via automation is with a combination of Config rule / remediation and AWS SSM documents (automation). I ended up automating this in CloudFormation templates, creating the needed role, policies, Config rule, etc., and referencing Amazon's SSM automation to enforce the remediation for any buckets without server access logging enabled.